# facebook webhook notification when someone like my page or liked or commented on my page post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, webhooks

I have a product website and a facebook page for that product.

1 .Is it possible to get the page like or post like/comment data through facebook webhook to my product website callback url in any format?

2.For using the webhook whether i need to create a facebook app?

Comment: Of course you need an app first. (And you will need HTTPS with a valid certificate, too.) What specific fields you can subscribe to, is listed in the docs.

Comment: I have crate and app and i have HTTPS call back url, how i proceed further to get the data in my call back url?

Comment: You follow the setup instructions in the documentation.

Comment: How to get an access token for my page?

Comment: When i am trying to create subscriptions i am getting the error "The URL couldn't be validated. Response does not match challenge, expected value = '740804019', received=' <!DOCTYPE ht...' " .

Comment: So your callback URL answered with a complete HTML document apparently, instead of just returning the challenge value it was sent - you need to go find out why.

Comment: How i can verify my call back url ?

Comment: By making a request that sends the same data as Facebook does ...?

Comment: How to add verify toke in my call back url?

Comment: In the verification stage, Facebook sends a verification token to your URL, and you have to return that same value.

Comment: is it possible using html?

Comment: No. Your script has to return the exact value it was send, and _only that_.

Answer (score 0):

```
public override void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < context.Request.QueryString.Count; i++)
            {
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(Server.MapPath("~") + "//Documents//Logs//APILog.txt", context.Request.QueryString[i]);
            } 
            if (context.Request.QueryString[2] == "My_new_token")
                context.Response.Write(context.Request.QueryString[1]);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           System.IO.File.AppendAllText(Server.MapPath("~") + "//Documents//Logs//APILog.txt", "Exception:" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```